# no mysql workbench in ubuntu 12.04 software center

Tags: software-center, mysql, repository, mysql-workbench

I have already installed MySQL workbench from the Software Center on a recent installation of Ubuntu 12.10 (32 bit) with no problems.  Since then, I just installed ubuntu 12.04 LTS on another machine (64 bit) and I can't find it in the software center.

Is there a way I can enable the repositories to make it available to me?  I know it exists for 12.10 so I am assuming it is available for 12.04.

Thanks for any input!

**UPDATE**

I switch my server in the software sources GUI (from Ubuntu Software Center go to Edit -> Software Sources..)

I was set to the Spain server (since I am in Spain) and I switched it to the Main Server, then did apt-get update and i was able to install with apt-get after that.

Answer (score 6):

In precise (12.04), quantal (12.10), and raring (13.04), the [`mysql-workbench` package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=names&suite=all&section=all&keywords=mysql-workbench) is in `universe`, so:

1. Open the "Software Sources" app, a.k.a. `software-properties-gtk`
2. Ensure the *"Community maintained free and open-source software"* checkbox is checked
3. Refresh your packages, either through a Refresh button or through `sudo apt-get update`
4. Install it via your favorite package management app, or `sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench`

Comment: 1 & 2 both are currently like that.  output from `apt-get install mysql-workbench`: unable to locate package mysql-workbench

Comment: Weird oÔ. Well, @TheLordOfTime's answer does the job!

Comment: i switch my server in the above mentioned software sources GUI.  I was set to the Spain server (since I am in Spain) and I switched it to the Main Server, then did `apt-get update` and i was able to install with apt-get after that.

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind what likely was the problem is that  you didn't actually apt-get update after enabling universe, which threw the initial issues.  Glad to see this fixed it though.

Comment: @TheLordofTime Thanks for the help.  Universe repos were enabled the whole time.  I just checked to make sure all the check boxes were there, so actually I think it was the server issue.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL Workbench might not be in the repositories for 12.04.

However, you can download and install a .deb from Oracle, [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/tools/workbench/), just make sure you choose the correct debian package under "Ubuntu Linux" option for the operating systems.

Comment: It is wrong. I installed it from repositories on my 12.04